# Test cases failing when run in TestNG parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

In TestNG parallel, test cases are failing when run in Parallel but run in series all cases are passing. May i Know what is the reason for this and how to solve it?

**Find my TestNG XML;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">

    <test thread-count="1" name="PSW">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_001_HomePage" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_002_iLoans" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_003_Investments" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_004_Fiduciary" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_005_Participants" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_006_Transaction" />
            <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_007_EmployeePages" />
        </classes>
    </test> 

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Your code trials please

Comment: What exactly is failing?

Comment: First test case is passing when i run in series but when i run in parallel the same test case is getting failed with element not found exception @jo

Comment: I am guessing your driver class is not set right. It is not handling the parallelization correctly. Share some code or some error

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue">

<parameter name="parallelSetup" value="tests" />
<parameter name="threadsNumber" value="3" />


<test name="Test" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_001_HomePage" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_002_iLoans" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_003_Investments" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_004_Fiduciary" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_005_Participants" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_006_Transaction" />
    <class name="testcases.PSW.TC_007_EmployeePages" />
    </classes>
</test>

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```